# How can I make a UITextField with padding on the left of the content?

Tags: uitextfield, padding

UITextField shows its content text bang against the left edge of the field, which is ugly and can be hard to read if the field has a visible border. UITextView, on the other hand, automatically has padding (blank space) around the text. I examined and experimented with all the UITextField properties but I don't see any way they can be used to get padding around the text.

I also tried calling drawText(in:CGRect) on the text field but it had no effect. But I'm not sure what CGRect is needed in that call. I tried different border styles including .none. I also tried making a blank UIView and assigning that to the text field's leftView property but that also had no effect. And I tried doing these things in viewDidLoad, viewDidAppear, and at the point where I'm writing the text into the textField. The text shows in the textField as expected but none of these other things seem to affect the textField's appearance in any way. It seems to me lots of people must show text in a UITextField and somehow get it padded on the left so I'm misunderstanding something but what???

Answer (score 0):

The following works for a field called "textField". It inserts padding by shifting the left side of the field's content 8 pixels right relative to the left edge of the textField:

textField.layer.sublayerTransform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(8, 0, 0);

This is given in an answer to a different question by user Dhiru (reputation 1285) in Nov. 2016. Thank you Dhiru!

I have to add that I am not familiar with either sublayerTransform or CATransform3DMakeTranslation so I can't be sure that this doesn't have some side effect that isn't immediately obvious. I'm a little worried that it's called "3D transform" whereas there is nothing 3D about my application. But at least for now this seems to answer the question.